# Fatal Python error: PyEval_SaveThread: NULL tstate using Theano

Tags: python, multithreading, keras, theano, multicore

I am training a VGG16 net in Keras with Theano backend on a cluster. 
While using multi-cpu as mentioned in the documentation http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/multi_cores.html I encounter the following error

Fatal Python error: PyEval_SaveThread: NULL tstate

I don't have any problems in using the following script test to check BLAS and OpenMP.

https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/master/theano/misc/elemwise_openmp_speedup.py

The error arises when the net starts training. I can't debug given that I'm not the cluster's administator.

Any help is deeply appreciated.
Thanks